# DynamoDB DocumentClient ConditionExpression - If Statement

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Wondering if there is any way to write a ConditionExpresson If statement on a Put, a pseudocode example of what i'm looking for:

```
IF email already exists AND verified equals false 
   THEN allow PUT
IF email already exists AND verified equals true
   THEN don't allow PUT
IF email does not exist
   THEN allow PUT
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Ended up figuring it out in a more elegant way:

```
query.Item = {
    email: email,
    verified: false,
    verifyToken: token
};

query.ExpressionAttributeNames = {
    '#verified' : 'verified'
};

query.ExpressionAttributeValues = {
    ':false' : false,
};

query.ConditionExpression = '#verified = :false OR attribute_not_exists(verified)';
```

Comment: is there a reason the last `verified` is plain?